# problems passing props to components

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I'm struggling to pass props down into some components. I have an array of data that I'm using but cant access the props to be able to use the data.

I can seem to access the props in a components folder but for some reason I cant access the props from within the same folder.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.

```
const homeOptions = [
  {
    name: "Create A Beast Workout",
    body: "Quick Start Workout",
    image: require("../assets/images/ChickSquat.jpg"),
    id: "1",
  },
  {
    name: "Beast Workout Diary",
    body: "Create and manage your workout shedule",
    image: require("../assets/images/DoubleBis.jpg"),
    id: "2",
  },
  {
    name: "Pre-Made Workouts",
    body: "Use one of our pre-made workouts",
    image: require("../assets/images/ChickA.jpg"),
    id: "3",
  },
  {
    name: "Statistics",
    body: "Analyse your personal statistics",
    image: require("../assets/images/WorkoutInProgress.jpg"),
    id: "4",
  },
  {
    name: "History",
    body: "Keep track of your workout history",
    image: require("../assets/images/ChickH.jpg"),
    id: "5",
  },
];

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <View style={Styles.containerTop}>
      <View>
        <HomeScreenImage style={Styles.top} />
        <View style={Styles.top}>
          <BigButton title="Beast" />
        </View>
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView style={Styles.flatListContainer}>
        <FlatList
          data={homeOptions}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={Styles.container}
              onPress={() =>
                props.navigation.navigate({
                  routeName: "StackNavigator",
                  params: {
                    cardId: props.info.id,
                    cardImage: props.info.image,
                    cardName: props.info.name,
                    cardBody: props.info.body,
                  },
                })
              }
            >
//////below is where im having the problem accessing props  /////////////////
              <View style={Styles.cardContainer}>
                <Image style={Styles.imageStyle} source={props.info.image} />
                <View style={Styles.infoStyle}>
                  <Text style={Styles.titleStyle}>{props.info.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={Styles.bodyTextStyle}>{props.info.body}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Props are used to pass info from parent to child or from libraries like Redux. It seems to me that you just need to import the file (and export from the file), it's got nothing to do with props.

Comment: Thank you very much iv been trying to figure it out for 3 days. Within 10 minutes of seeing your response I found the solution. I used the {item.id} to solve it.